# jQuery Wikipedia API is not working

Tags: jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get the first ten sentences of 5 Wikipedia pages using the MediaWiki API. I've got a query working in the API sandbox but for some reason my `getJSON()` call is not working. Here's my code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var input = $("#wikisearch").val();
    var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api/php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&indexpageids=1&generator=allpages&exsentences=10&explaintext=1&gapfrom=" + input + "&gaplimit=5&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(link, function(data) { 
         var array = data.query.pageids; 
         alert(array);
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me why the JSON call isn't working?

Comment: What's the error you're experiencing?

Comment: Nothing happens, I'm not getting the array alerted and none of the other code I've tried in the getJSON does anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You have an error in the url: it should be `api.php` not `api/php`.
2. `console.log` the data before you process it.
3. You can add error handling by adding a `.fail()` handler to capture any failure in the future.

Comment: I made those changes, nothing is appearing in the console when I do console.log(data)? it's not failing, I added the fail event handler and if I mess with the link it does fail, so I don't think I'm handling the data correctly?

Comment: Probably. But if you log `data` and nothing is shown, you may have a network issue. Check the Network pane in Developer Tools while running the code. You should see a transaction with 200 status for Wikipedia. Double click to see what came back. If nothing, or different status - there's your issue.

Comment: So that helped me figure out which link I should be using, it's working now but it only changes the html I'm trying to change for a split second before the page reloads - not sure why that's happening?

Comment: I fixed it!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool! Mark as the right answer if you feel it helped.